# Where is the "Upload new apk"-button in the developer console?

Tags: upload, apk

I feel that this is a stupid question, but how the heck do I upload a new APK-file? I have already uploaded a apk-file when i wanted to configure in app billing, and now i want upload a new updated apk-file. How do I do that? Where is the button?

Answer (score 0):

In the developer console, click on APK on the left hand side, then the button should appear.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The site was i Swedish for me, and it sed "Upload to betaversion". I think it might be a bug